# WebStorm editor tab background colour

Tags: webstorm

I want to use a light theme in WebStorm 2017.1 but for some reason the editor tabs are always dark.

I can change the font colour but that also changes it in the project tree view which has a white background.

The theme under Appearance is set to IntelliJ and the editor theme is set to default but I have tried it with many combinations.

Is this a bug or is there a setting I haven't found yet?

[image]

Comment: This might sound silly but have you opened and closed the editor after switching the theme? I've found sometimes it's buggy until i restart the editor

Comment: Yeah, it seems to reset everything except the editor theme to dark after a restart.  So the project tree, menus etc all change to dark.

Comment: Please show a list of all custom plugins that you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Material Theme plugin, disabled it and everything looks fine.

Thanks to @LazyOne for pointing me in the right direction.